# iOS7.1 HFP prompts in our apps

Tags: ios, audio, bluetooth

I've researched over the web and even asked Apple for this, still didn't get an answer I need.

I have an iOS app which must alert user on some alarms. iOS device and this app are used in car. Alarms are rare but extremely important. When user connects iOS device(iPhone) to cars audio over Bluetooth Classic and user has Bluetooth selected as input, alarm is hear and everything works ok.
Problem is, when user listens to radio, CDs, or browsing mp3s on USB input, when alarm comes, it's not heard!

I need a way to sound the alarm like in iOS7.1 navigation, over HFP so it does not matter which source is selected on the car audio.

I've checked every framework on iOS which could have some relation to Bluetooth and it's audio profiles with no luck.

Any ideas?
Somebody implemented this already?
Need a push in a right direction.

Thanks!